# SquashTA - Integrating existing tests

Tags: automated-tests, squash

We are looking forward to using squashTA to manage our tests.  The problem we are facing is that we already have a big automated tests collection and aren't able to make them run via squash TM using squash TA.

Our tests are using junit+selenium WebDriver+SpringFramework.
Currently, we launch our automated tests via maven (in commandLine), and we have a jenkins server running them regularly.

We tried to reuse our tests in a squash TA project, putting them in `src/squashta/resources/selenium/java`

But code in this folder doesn't even support java packages.  It's like the java in the example isn't real java but a fake java parse by squashTA.

Is there any mean of using such already existing tests with squash(TA/TM) ?
Or, any alternatives you know that could do the job ? (we are currently using testlink and must change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your selenium test is in :

src/squashTA/resources/selenium-test/src/main/java/org/squashtest/ta/selenium/PetStoreTest.java

With a such structure, the test automation script to run the selenium test (which is in the package org.squashtest.ta.selenium) is :

```
TEST :
LOAD selenium-test/src/test AS seleniumTestSource
CONVERT seleniumTestSource TO script.java(compile) AS seleniumTestCompiled
CONVERT seleniumTestCompiled TO script.java.selenium2(script) USING $(org.squashtest.ta.selenium.PetStoreTest) AS seleniumTest
EXECUTE execute WITH seleniumTest AS seleniumResult
ASSERT seleniumResult IS success
```

If your selenium test has some dependencies to other libraries (like to spring in your case), you have to add those depencencies as dependency of the squash-ta-maven-plugin in the pom.xml of your Squash TA project

Comment: Thank you !  Unfortunately, my team decided to abandon the ship and moved to using TestRail.  But I'm still glad to have your solution.

Comment: @bfranchet I used your format to run my test script but it's not working, my test script path is as follows:

src/squashTA/resources/com/java/src/main/org/ta/UntitledTestCase2.java

and the following is my code:

SETUP :

LOAD com/java/src/main AS javaTestCodeFile

TEST :

CONVERT javaTestCodeFile TO script.java (compile) AS seleniumTestCompiled
CONVERT seleniumTestCompiled TO script.java.selenium2 (script) USING $(org.ta.UntitledTestCase2) AS seleniumTest
EXECUTE execute WITH seleniumTest AS javaTestresults
ASSERT javaTestresults IS success